# grapheneos build with custom bootanimation

Tags: android, operating-system, android-source

i am trying to build grapheneos for pixel 6 with custom bootanimation
i created bootanimation.zip file according to instructions but can't figure out the location to put it in.  since the usual location, system/media/bootanimation.zip is giving me an Error:

> offending entries: system/media/bootanimation.zip

and the build fails.can anyone help me to understand what i am doing wrong ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Here is correct answer**:
For changing of animation for emulator x86_64 you need to replace

> PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += 
> device/generic/goldfish/data/media/test/swirl_136x144_mpeg4.mp4:data/media/0/test/CtsMediaTestCases-1.4/swirl_136x144_mpeg4.mp4 
> device/generic/goldfish/data/media/test/swirl_132x130_mpeg4.mp4:data/media/0/test/CtsMediaTestCases-1.4/swirl_132x130_mpeg4.mp4 
> device/generic/goldfish/data/media/test/swirl_130x132_mpeg4.mp4:data/media/0/test/CtsMediaTestCases-1.4/swirl_130x132_mpeg4.mp4 
> device/generic/goldfish/data/media/test/swirl_144x136_mpeg4.mp4:data/media/0/test/CtsMediaTestCases-1.4/swirl_144x136_mpeg4.mp4 
> device/generic/goldfish/data/media/test/swirl_128x128_mpeg4.mp4:data/media/0/test/CtsMediaTestCases-1.4/swirl_128x128_mpeg4.mp4 \

to

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += 
device/generic/goldfish/data/media/test/swirl_136x144_mpeg4.mp4:data/media/0/test/CtsMediaTestCases-1.4/swirl_136x144_mpeg4.mp4 
device/generic/goldfish/data/media/test/swirl_132x130_mpeg4.mp4:data/media/0/test/CtsMediaTestCases-1.4/swirl_132x130_mpeg4.mp4 
device/generic/goldfish/data/media/test/swirl_130x132_mpeg4.mp4:data/media/0/test/CtsMediaTestCases-1.4/swirl_130x132_mpeg4.mp4 
device/generic/goldfish/data/media/test/swirl_144x136_mpeg4.mp4:data/media/0/test/CtsMediaTestCases-1.4/swirl_144x136_mpeg4.mp4 
device/generic/goldfish/data/media/test/swirl_128x128_mpeg4.mp4:data/media/0/test/CtsMediaTestCases-1.4/swirl_128x128_mpeg4.mp4 
device/generic/goldfish/data/media/bootanimation.zip:$(PRODUCT_OUT)/product/media/bootanimation.zip

device/generic/goldfish/x86_64-vendor.mk

Your bootanimzation.zip needs to be in device/generic/goldfish/data/media

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/bootanimation/BootAnimation.cpp

In case of Graphene it uses images from assets by default.

I didn't see your mk file and the output. But I'd suggested to overwrite some output files in your mk file and put your bootanimation to one from locations listed in [BootAnimation.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/bootanimation/BootAnimation.cpp) via PRODUCT_COPY_FILES.

> ## Something like here:

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \    packages/services/Car/car_product/car_ui_portrait/bootanimation/bootanimation.zip:system/media/bootanimation.zip

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Got your question wrong. I suppose you meant artifacts path requirements?